# tools to visualize an abstract tree

Tags: c++, c

I wonder there are any tools or online tools which one can construct tree just giving datas. ex ; after giving datas, I want get a picture like ; [google picture](http://lh5.ggpht.com/_1SkEgLzvHUY/SwgaAC9wt5I/AAAAAAAAARs/Kk_guWSE38g/2.JPG)

Comment: Your question is not very clear but you may be looking for http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphviz

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look into [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/), and its descriptive language [DOT](http://www.graphviz.org/content/dot-language).

Answer (score 0):

If you want an online/web style tool, you can try using the organizational chart graph from [google charts](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/orgchart.html) which is very simple to use, though the 'square-ness' of the chart might annoy some, or you can try a more fancy flash API like [Flare](http://flare.prefuse.org/) (the [Demo](http://flare.prefuse.org/demo) contains various types of 'trees' under "layouts").